K-Means: How To Solve Error: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'
I am new in Machine Learning and I have a task that required me to perform unsupervised learning, so I decided to use K-Means.
I using Python to code. I have imported the data (my data is from a csv file) into Google Colab. My data has 7 features, and I need to plot the clusters, but I get the error: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'.
This is my code:
This part is how I decide my k value. I use Elbow Method.
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

DATA = "/content/information.csv"
df = pd.read_csv (DATA, header=0)
data = list(zip(x_train["date"], x_train["a"], x_train["b"], x_train["c"], x_train["d"], x_train["e"], x_train["f"]))
print(data)

inertias = []

for i in range(1,40):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    kmeans.fit(data) 
    inertias.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1,40), inertias, marker='o')
plt.title('Elbow method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Inertia')
plt.show()

And this is where it goes wrong:
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5) 
kmeans.fit(data)  
plt.scatter(x_train["date"], x_train["a"], x_train["b"], x_train["c"], x_train["d"], x_train["e"], x_train["f"], c=kmeans.labels_) 
plt.show()  

The error seems to indicated that the part that goes wrong is at the plt.scatter() line.
I tried with 2 features, it works, but when it comes to 7 features, I get error message. What could have gone wrong?

To plot more pairs, you need to call plt.scatter() multiple times. Possibly in a loop, depending on what you want to use for x and y

c is the fourth parameter, so you are setting it to x_train["c"].  You are also setting it to kmeans.labels_.

The plt.scatter function does not accept multiple datasets to plot, you can only pass an x and y. So, as suggested in the comments, you'll need to loop through what you want to plot.
y_cols = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
for y_col in y_cols:
    plt.scatter(x_train["date"], x_train[y_col], c=kmeans.labels_)

You didn't provide enough code for us to run, so I cannot test this to see if I made any mistakes.
